# How to create interconnected mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Here I've two different tables named as **`usermaster`** and **`userdetails`**. What I want to do is, create a trigger on table usermaster on after insert and in this trigger, I want to update the same table but another row.

```
 BEGIN
    Declare UserCode varchar(50);
    Declare BasePlan,CurrentPlan decimal(10,4);
    Declare BaseDate,CurrentDate datetime;

    Set UserCode=Trim(new.us_usercode);
    Select ap.ap_planCost,us.us_edtm into BasePlan,BaseDate
from us_uxusermaster us inner join cm_clientmaster cm inner join pl_planlist pl inner join ap_affiliateplan ap 
on us.us_usercode=cm.cm_affiliatecode and pl.pl_id=us.us_planListId and pl.pl_ap_id=ap.ap_id where cm.cm_usercode=UserCode;

    Select ap.ap_planCost,us.us_edtm into CurrentPlan,CurrentDate 
from us_uxusermaster us  inner join pl_planlist pl inner join ap_affiliateplan ap on pl.pl_id=us.us_planListId and pl.pl_ap_id=ap.ap_id where us.us_usercode=UserCode;



    if(CurrentPlan>=BasePlan)
    Then
    If(DateDiff(BaseDate,CurrentDate)<=30)
    Then
    Update us_uxusermaster set us_eby='update' where us_usercode=(Select cm.cm_affiliatecode from cm_clientmaster cm where cm.cm_usercode=UserCode);
    End If;
    End If;

    END
```

But every time I do so it gives me an error that I cant use the same table for Updation.

So I'm creating two triggers first on after insert of **`usermaster`** and in this trigger, It updates table **`userdetails`** and one more trigger on after update of table **`userdetails`** which updates the table **`usermaster`**.

Is this mechanism is right or any other solution exist which is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the same table from within the trigger, here's what the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) says:

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already
>   being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the
>   function or trigger.

Also, you seem to have cyclic dependency (via triggers) between `usermaster` and `userdetails` tables, something I would strongly recommend moving away from. Another approach would be to perform these updates (from the application) within a transaction.